# malloc with user input

Tags: c, malloc, scanf

I'm trying to make a program where a user inputs a string then if they want to enter a letter they want to replace and what with. I want to use malloc to set the array but how would I do it with scanf?

Please can someone help.

Thanks!

This is what the program looks before going to the replace method:

```
char *s,x,y;

printf("Please enter String \n");
scanf("%s ", malloc(s));

printf("Please enter the character you want to replace\n");
scanf("%c ", &x); 

printf("Please enter replacment \n");
scanf("%c ", &y);

prinf("%s",s);
```

Comment: I think you want POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) (not part of the C99 Standard).

Comment: Your use of malloc is horribly wrong: Malloc takes the number of bytes and returns a pointer. You pass it a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't know the size of the user input beforehand, so you need to dynamically allocate more memory if the user input hasn't ended yet.

An example would be:

```
//don't forget to free() the result when done!
char *read_with_alloc(FILE *f) {
    size_t bufsize = 8;
    char *buf = (char *) malloc(bufsize);
    size_t pos = 0;

    while (1) {
        int c = fgetc(f);

        //read until EOF, 0 or newline is read
        if (c < 0 or c == '\0' or c == '\n') {
            buf[pos] = '\0';
            return buf;
        }

        buf[pos++] = (char) c;

        //enlarge buf to hold whole string
        if (pos == bufsize) {
            bufsize *= 2;
            buf = (char *) realloc((void *) buf, bufsize);
        }
    }
}
```

A pragmatic alternative solution would be to limit the buf size (for example, to 256 characters), and to make sure that only that number of bytes is read:

```
char buf[256]; //alternative: char *buf = malloc(256), make sure you understand the precise difference between these two!
if (scanf("%255s", buf) != 1) {
   //something went wrong! your error handling here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%s ", malloc(s));
```

What does this mean? s uninitialized is pointer, it can have any value, say `0x54654`, it is Undefined Behavior.

Your code should be,

```
int size_of_intput = 100; //decide size of string
s = malloc(size_of_intput);
scanf("%s ", s);
```

Comment: You should __always__ make sure that no buffer overflows are caused. A >= 100-character user input might very well cause a heap corruption with your code! Pass `scanf("%99s ", s)` instead, and check the return value of scanf.

Comment: @mic_e Great advice. Not knowing `%99s` possible.